# Are these classes that I wrote broken in terms of thread-safety? Also, are ManagedBeans used in different Threads?

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, jsf, thread-safety

I wrote this class here

```
@Component
public class LoginDao {
    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public List<Map<String, Object>> getUser(final String username, final String password) {
        return jdbcTemplate.queryForList("select * from users where username=? and password=?", new Object[]{username, password});
    }
}
```

Now, it is used by a managedbean in JSF, which is just a bean created and used when a request is made (if you use default scope).

```
@ManagedBean
public class Login implements Serializable {
    @ManagedProperty("#{loginDao}")
    private LoginDao loginDao;
//..do something with loginDao
}
```

I am scared that this is completely broken because what if when the Login bean created by JSF goes to use that loginDao, which is an injected object, and see that loginDao's field jdbcTemplate to be null?

This might happen if the Login bean used to handle the request, is going to run in a separate thread if the Webserver uses that separate thread to handle that request and since LoginDao's field jdbcTemplate is not final and set in the constructor before the running of the Login bean, couldn't that jdbcTemplate be seen as null in the Login instance? Is the way to fix this to make the jdbcTemplate to be volatile?

Also, now this makes me question everything I ever wrote with spring and JSF. Is it impossible to write thread-safe classes when using the @Autowired annotation unless you use the volatile keyword on that field?

I am really worried about using a dependency injection framework now. I mean, is there even a guarantee that objects that were injected by the container will not be seen as null for its reference or in a non up to date state?

Comment: It all depends on the scope...

Comment: I would say no they aren't... There is no state in the beans... The `JdbcTemplate` is thread safe and doesn't count as state that can be modified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Autowired beans are injected during initialization, so in this case jdbcTemplate should never be null when handling a request. However, if you want to be completely sure, yo can inject it through a constructor, which is the recommended method:

```
@Component
public class LoginDao {

    private final JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Autowired
    public LoginDao(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
      this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
    }

    public List<Map<String, Object>> getUser(final String username, final String password) {
        return jdbcTemplate.queryForList("select * from users where username=? and password=?", new Object[]{username, password});
    }
}
```

Effectively as you say, its very possible that multiple requests will be handled by different threads, and what would happen depends entirely on the defined scopes:

- The default scope in spring is 'singleton', so in this case LoginDAO will have only one instance in the application serving all requests. In your posted code this is not a problem, as JdbcTemplate is thread-safe.

> Also, now this makes me question everything I ever wrote with spring
>   and JSF. Is it impossible to write thread-safe classes when using the
>   @Autowired annotation unless you use the volatile keyword on that
>   field?

Its completely possible. And it will depende mostly on what you need. You can have a singleton bean which performs its operations in a thread-safe manner (dependes on your code and the libraries you use), or you can have non-thread safe bean working with a 'request scope' (ie: one bean instance for each request), or anything in the middle (there are 5 scope types in spring).

Setting fields as volatile if for a complete different purpose. the volatile keyword indicates that a field value will be continuously being modified by multiple threads, so the JVM will not cache its value inside threads to prevent race conditions, and will manage asignations in an atomic way. This will only protect the field value, but if the value is an object, it will not protect the values inside that object.

> I am really worried about using a dependency injection framework now.
>   I mean, is there even a guarantee that objects that were injected by
>   the container will not be seen as null for its reference or in a non
>   up to date state?

At least in my experience with spring, i have never encounter that problem. Spring does a very good job initializing an preparing everything on startup so you don't have to worry about that. However, the constructor autowiring method indicated previously is recommended precisely because give the programmer more safety about exactly your issues.

Comment: That example with the constructor would guarantee visibility when passing that fully constructed bean to other threads and hence your answer takes the checkmark and upvote.

Well I understand what you said about visibility, but volatile also gives visibility guarantees when publishing objects. Nevertheless your explanation is simple and concise explanation.

Hmm. about the last point, yet again the problem with the injection is that even though those objects are initialized and prepared, for other threads using that, they might see otherwise,I guess the constructor method with final is key

Comment: Unless you are using your own threads and using direct references to beans instead of using the spring provided APIs, i can't think of a case in which something like that could happen.
Depending on the used scope, you will have either a singleton bean already initialized, or a bean proxy which will initialize the bean on each request (in the case of request scope), and deal with that kind of problems for you.

edit: forgot to mention that spring will not process any request until the main thread has finished setting up the application, hence at that point beans will be already initialized.